# What is the opposite of Type.MakeByRefType

Tags: .net, reflection

The [`Type.MakeByRefType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makebyreftype.aspx) method in .NET returns a by-ref version of a type, e.g. passing the type of `System.Int32` returns a type representing `System.Int32&`.

However, if you already have a `System.Int32&`, what is the mechanism for obtaining a plain old `System.Int32`? There doesn't seem to be an opposite method to remove the by-ref modifier.

At the moment I've put a hack in place which re-builds the assembly-qualified name without an `&` at the end of the type name and then loads that type, but this is horribly dirty...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the docs for [`IsByRef`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isbyref?view=net-5.0#System_Type_IsByRef), you can use [`Type.GetElementType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx).

This is also true for types for which [`IsArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isarray?view=net-5.0) or [`IsPointer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.ispointer?view=net-5.0) is `true`.

```cs
var typeInt = typeof(int);
var typeIntRef = typeInt.MakeByRefType();
var typeIntArray = typeInt.MakeArrayType();
var typeIntPointer = typeInt.MakePointerType();

Debug.Assert(typeIntRef.GetElementType() == typeInt);
Debug.Assert(typeIntArray.GetElementType() == typeInt);
Debug.Assert(typeIntPointer.GetElementType() == typeInt);
```

Comment: Yep that seems to do the trick, cheers! I feel a bit dumb seeing as it was in the docs for a related attribute... but never mind.

Comment: GetElementType is not most inituative name. ive struggled for this too. ty