# How to get the underlying type of a ByRef type from Reflection.ParmeterInfo

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I want to find the types of all the parameters of a given method using reflection, but I'm having trouble with parameters that are passed by reference (`ref` keyword).

For example, say the original method has a parameter of type ref int like so:

```
public int DoStuff(ref int count) {...}
```

Starting with the `MethodInfo` object, when I examine the `ParameterInfo` for the parameter I find a `ParameterType` property where the value is `System.Int32&`.  I see that I can drill down into `ParameterType.IsByRef` and see that it is true.  This all makes sense, but what I can't figure out is how to find the fact that the underlying type of the parameter (the type referred to) is `System.Int32`.

Neither `typeof(System.Int32&)` nor `typeof(ref System.Int32)` compile so I don't know how to make a programmatic comparison like:

```
if (typeof(System.Int32&) == ParameterType)
```

or

```
if (ParameterType.IsByRef && typeof(System.Int32) == ParameterType.UnderlyingType)
```

Comment: In other words https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607130/what-is-the-opposite-of-type-makebyreftype ?

Comment: if (typeof(int).MakeByRefType() == ParameterType)

Comment: Thanks!  Converting Int32 to Int32& as suggested by Hans Passant would work, but the answer to 607130 as linked by @JeremyLakeman is more direct.  GetElementType() is the answer I was looking for.  I just didn't didn't know that "What is the opposite of MakeByRefType?" was the question ;-).